# Java timestamps. checking if near time, it is the time or over

Tags: java

I want to know if it is possible to check the time. then find the nearest 10 minute. if it is over the nearest 10 min (lets say I check at :12) I want to know how to use that. or is it is within the 5 minutes before the next one (lets say around :25 where :30 is the nearest 10 min) is it possible to know this as well?

thanks in advance. I literally don't have a clue how to do this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As currently written, its hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: please give more infos about what you understand under `nearest` probably with more examples which demonstrate the positive test and the negative test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.Yes.

```
Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTE)
```

returns the current minute count within the hour.

To find the nearest 10 min, assuming `minutes` contains the current minute count, you do:

```
int nearest = ((minutes+5) / 10)*10 % 60;
```

It uses integer division by 10 to "round down" to nearest 10, but first 5 is added such that 25 becomes 30, then divided by 10 becomes 3, then multiplied by 3 becomes 30.

Lastly modulus 60 because otherwise 56 minutes would be rounded to 60 which you cannot have.

The whole math part of the last formula is the same as is often used to round decimal numbers (add 0.5, then truncate it to whole integer - if it was 0.5 or more to start with then adding 0.5 gives 1 or more to ensure it rounds up when appropriate).

Comment: thanks. I can work with this part. now its just a easy part of comparing whether your past the closest 10 or withing the range of the next  one.

Comment: The code does that. The whole "int nearest ..." line is about rounding it to nearest 10-minute-number.

Comment: yes I found it. also I added some checks and now I have 3 lines I can work with. one for the 5 - 10 mark, one after the 10 mark but before the 5 and one on the 10 mark.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a TimeStamp object and compare the current timestamp to the timestap that you could set for 10 minutes later or earlier. Timestamp offers plenty of methods to compare to other Timestamps that would be later.

I encourage you to take a look at the methods of the Oracle Docs.

See: [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html)

```
java.util.Date date= new java.util.Date();
     System.out.println(new Timestamp(date.getTime()));
```

Can be used to get the current Timestamp. You can then compare it to with `TimeStamp.compareTo(Timestamp ts)` and check whether it is within 10 minutes(in Milliseconds of course) that way.